# C++ Snippet to C# Bitwise Operators

Tags: c#, c++, bit-manipulation

I am having a hard time porting this part of C++ to C#.  I keep getting Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'long' which makes sense.  So what would the equivalent be?

```
    while ((c <= combinations) && ((round_set & (1 << cList[c].one)) || (round_set & (1 << cList[c].two)) || (cUsed[c])))
                   {
                   fprintf( stdout, "C: %d\n", c);
                    c++;
                    }

while ((c <= combinations) && ((round_set & (1 << cList[c].one)) || (round_set & (1 << cList[c].two)) || (cUsed[c])))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("C: {0}", c);

                                c++;
                            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++, unlike C#, lets you treat an integer value as if it were a boolean value, ad-hoc, where any integer `0` is false, and any integer other than `0` is true. C# does not allow this.

To achieve the same effect in C# you must explicitely perform the check I just described, so instead of

```
if( (expr) || ... ) { }
```

you want

```
if( (expr) != 0 || ... ) { }
```

And in fact the latter is still perfectly acceptable (and sometimes encouraged for clarity) in C++.